# type change for "link primary key value"

Tags: palantir-foundry

the supporting dateset primary key is an 'integer', the type was changed in the cleaning code for the primary key to a 'string' and then links were built between objects_types. edits were done in the repository to restore the primary key to its orginal type (integer). Now getting an error as the data type for the primary key in the lync shows a 'string'.  Is there a way to edit the
link keys ?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the link type by selecting Link types from the list at the left hand side of the ontology management application.

[image]

Once there you can access the link you want to edit and update the primary keys using the dropdown below the cardinality boxes.

[image]